# How can I open a link in react web app without giving user name and password again?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I have a running react web application with protected routes. We are using JSON web tokens. We also using Redux saga. I want to provide a link and This need to be open in a new tab. But when the user logged in and click on the link, the link opens in a new tab but it asks user name and password again. I want to share the current state with the app in the new tab.

Answer (score 0):

How are you storing the JWT? The most common way to do it is to store the JWT in cookies which automatically get sent on every request in the same domain. As long as the JWT is in a cookie, the cookie gets passed to the server, and the server checks for and uses the JWT payload, you should be able to open a new tab just fine.

Comment: @MK we sent the token in the header